404 on Airflow stable APIs on local deployment
I am not able to enable the Stable Airflow APIs on local. It always errors out with HTTP 404 error.
INFO - 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2024 22:14:09] "GET /api/dags?limit=100&only_active=true HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Below are the airflow configs for API section:
[api]
enable_experimental_api = False
auth_backends = airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth,airflow.api.auth.backend.session
maximum_page_limit = 100
fallback_page_limit = 100
google_oauth2_audience = 
google_key_path = 
access_control_allow_headers = 
access_control_allow_methods = 
access_control_allow_origins = 
enable_xcom_deserialize_support = False

Airflow version:
Apache Airflow
version                | 2.9.3                                                                            
executor               | SequentialExecutor 

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

I realised that the API should be
localhost:8080/api/v1

instead of
localhost:8080/api/

It was missing /v1 in the postman I was using. Hence, the 404 error.
